# can i run futurize --stage2 changes without having a dependency on future package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I would like to support my python 2.7 code with 2/3 compatibility. I have chosen Futurize to do the changes. while running --stage2 changes with Futurize works fine and all my tests run good. the problem is that the tools that work with the repository functionalities on which the changes are done require to install future (pip install future). Is there a way to remove that dependency on the tool's side so that it doesn't require me to install future.

If the above doesn't work my other option will be to do my changes with Modernize

--stage2 introduces builtins which will give a problem if future is uninstalled

```
    from __future__ import print_function
  + from __future__ import unicode_literals
  + from builtins import str
    from openshift import *
```

Expected result : any method to use futurize without having future installed on the tool side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to remove the dependency on future and so i used [Modernize](https://python-modernize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) whose changes do not require any such dependency as above